# I am trying to write a prime number recogniser but for some reason it won't work

Tags: php

It won't recognise the else statement near the bottom and just won't echo it.

```
<?php

$numval = $_GET["num"];

// see if string is all numbers

if (is_numeric($numval) == 1) {
    
    // if string is all numbers change its type to integer

    settype($numval, "int");

    // divide numval by every number and see if it is whole
    // create a while loop with $i = 2 and $stop = false
    // loop dividing $numval by $i,
    // if it is decimal then $i++ and  repeat
    // if a number is found that fits into it then set $stop to true and echo it is not prime
    // if nothing is found that fits into $numval then set $stop to true and print

    $i = 2;
    $stop = false;

    while ( $i < $numval  &&  $stop == false) {

        if ( floor( $numval / $i ) != $numval / $i ) {
 
            $i++;
        
        } elseif ( floor( $numval / $i ) == $numval / $i ) {

            echo "The number is not prime";
            $stop = true;

        } else {

            echo "Number is prime";
            $stop = true;

        }
    }
}
?>

<br>

<p>Enter whole positive number that isn't 0 or 1</p>

<form>

<input name="num" type="text">
<input type="submit">

</form>
```

Comment: Your conditions are "If is not equal", "is equal", or other. There is no condition that would reach other because it's either equal or not equal.

Comment: You basically have `if (a) {...} elseif (!a) {...} else {...}` The `else` will never be executed like that.

Comment: Can you define a condition in which that `else` block *should* be reached?  For what values of `$numval` and `$i` do you expect that to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your else condition will never be reached because your if/elseif are true/false. There is no third option. Instead, move the echo outside of the loop, and just set a flag inside of the loop for when it's not prime.

```
if (is_numeric($numval) == 1) {

    // if string is all numbers change its type to integer

    settype($numval, "int");

    // divide numval by every number and see if it is whole
    // create a while loop with $i = 2 and $stop = false
    // loop dividing $numval by $i,
    // if it is decimal then $i++ and  repeat
    // if a number is found that fits into it then set $stop to true and echo it is not prime
    // if nothing is found that fits into $numval then set $stop to true and print

    $i = 2;
    $not_prime = false;

    while ( $i < $numval  &&  $not_prime == false) {

        if ( floor( $numval / $i ) != $numval / $i ) {

            $i++;

        } elseif ( floor( $numval / $i ) == $numval / $i ) {

            $not_prime = true;
        }
    }

    echo $not_prime ? "Number is not prime" : "Number is prime";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first two conditions are already collectively exhaustive:

```
if ( floor( $numval / $i ) != $numval / $i ) {
  //...
} elseif ( floor( $numval / $i ) == $numval / $i ) {
  //...
}
```

That is, they already cover *all possible scenarios*.  It's logically the same as:

```
if (true) {
  //...
} elseif (false) {
  //...
}
```

There doesn't exist any scenario in which at least *one* of these two conditions is not satisfied.  So any additional `elseif` or `else` blocks are superfluous.  They're allowed because they are syntactically valid, but will never be reached because the logic for them will never be satisfied.